# How to add new group for project role? JIRA 7 API, JAVA

Tags: java, jira-plugin, role

Lets say I have *project role* ***developers*** and want to asing a new *group* called ***database_developers*** to it. My problem is that I can not find a way to create instance of ***RoleActor***. I am guessing that implementation I need is `com.atlassian.jira.security.roles.actor.GroupRoleActorFactory.GroupRoleActor` however there is no such factory.

**EDIT 1:** I think I found it (overlooked this method):

```
RoleActorFactory roleActorFactory = ComponentAccessor.getComponentOfType(RoleActorFactory.class);
```